# Why I have this type error in official code for react hook form?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hook-form

I am using Nextjs 13, React Hook form 7, and Typescript.

I want to use react hook form's watch hook, but I have Argument types that do not match the error of the parameters.

**My code:**

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

interface IFormInputs {
  name: string;
  showAge: boolean;
  age: number;
}

function App() {
  const {
    register,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit,
  } = useForm<IFormInputs>();
  const watchShowAge = watch("showAge", false); // you can supply default value as second argument
  const watchAllFields = watch(); // when pass nothing as argument, you are watching everything
  const watchFields = watch(["showAge", "age"]); // you can also target specific fields by their names

  // Callback version of watch.  It's your responsibility to unsubscribe when done.
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = watch((value, { name, type }) => console.log(value, name, type));
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, [watch]);

  const onSubmit = (data: IFormInputs) => console.log(data);

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input {...register("name", { required: true, maxLength: 50 })} />
        <input type="checkbox" {...register("showAge")} />
        {/* based on yes selection to display Age Input*/}
        {watchShowAge && <input type="number" {...register("age", { min: 50 })} />}
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

**The error picture:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BplnY.png)

**And official sandbox:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-watch-v7-ts-8et1d?file=/src/index.tsx

I tried to let tsconfig's strict be false, but I still have this error. And not only the watch function of useForm but also the useWatch function also have errors.

**My code and official code:**

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm, useWatch, Control } from "react-hook-form";

import "./styles.css";

interface FormInputs {
  firstName: string;
}

function FirstNameWatched({ control }: { control: Control<FormInputs> }) {
  const firstName = useWatch({
    control,
    name: "firstName", // without supply name will watch the entire form, or ['firstName', 'lastName'] to watch both
    defaultValue: "default" // default value before the render
  });

  return <p>Watch: {firstName}</p>; // only re-render at the component level, when firstName changes
}

function App() {
  const { register, control, handleSubmit } = useForm<FormInputs>();

  const onSubmit = (data: FormInputs) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label>First Name:</label>
      <input {...register("firstName")} />
      <input type="submit" />
      <FirstNameWatched control={control} />
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**The official document:**
https://react-hook-form.com/docs/usewatch

**Official sandbox:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-ts-usewatch-h9i5e

**The error message:**

```
Argument type {defaultValue: string, name: string, control: Control<FormInputs>} is not assignable to parameter type {defaultValue?: DeepPartialSkipArrayKey<DeepPartial<FormInputs>>, control?: Control<DeepPartial<FormInputs>>, disabled?: boolean, exact?: boolean} and near
```

**The useWatch function:**

```
const firstName = useWatch({
    control,
    name: "firstName", // without supply name will watch the entire form, or ['firstName', 'lastName'] to watch both
    defaultValue: "default", // default value before the render
  });
```

Comment: Those sandbox links don't show any type errors.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But same code in my project will have the errors.